# How to estimate the epsilon-cover for H?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

> I saw this question,tried to solve but I face some doubts , Hence posting here

[question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4482847/how-can-i-create-cover-for-hs-weight-space)

$N(W_H,\epsilon,d)$ = minimum size of an epsilon cover of the weight space of H in the metric d

I know a  trivial way to construct such a cover of $W_H$ is to take the product of an epsilon' sized cover of $W_B$ and $W_T$ in the metric d. Then an upperbound on $N(W_H,\epsilon,d)$ is a product of the sizes of the epsilon' covers of $W_B$ and $W_T$ that I choose - and these individual  upperbounds are already known because of B and T spaces being Lipschitz.

So my main job is now  to estimate what must epsilon be here and what minimal assumptions one needs on the distribution so that the product of these epsilon covers of $W_B$ and $W_T$ give an epsilon cover of $W_H$

and I am lacking here. How to choose such epsilon. Is there any formal process? Kindly help me out!

---

$$
\mathcal{B}:=\left\{\mathrm{B}_{\boldsymbol{w}} \mid \mathrm{B}: \mathbb{R}^{d_{1}} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{q}, \operatorname{Lip}\left(\mathrm{B}_{\boldsymbol{w}}\right) \leq L_{B} \&\|\boldsymbol{w}\| \leq W_{B}\right\}
$$
$$
\mathcal{T}:=\left\{\mathbf{T}_{\boldsymbol{w}} \mid \mathbf{T}: \mathbb{R}^{d_{2}} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{q}, \operatorname{Lip}\left(\mathbf{T}_{\boldsymbol{w}}\right) \leq L_{T} \&\|\boldsymbol{w}\| \leq W_{T}\right\}
$$
Now consider the following function class of all possible inner-products between the two,
$$
\mathcal{H}:=\left\{h_{\boldsymbol{w}_{b}, \boldsymbol{w}_{t}} \mid \mathbb{R}^{d_{1}} \times \mathbb{R}^{d_{2}} \ni(s, p) \mapsto h(s, p):=\left\langle\mathrm{B}_{\boldsymbol{w}_{b}}(s), \mathbf{T}_{\boldsymbol{w}_{t}}(p)\right\rangle \in \mathbb{R}, \mathrm{B}_{\boldsymbol{w}_{b}} \in \mathcal{B} \& \mathbf{T}_{\boldsymbol{w}_{t}} \in \mathcal{T}\right\}
$$